# Notify when export completes in Premiere - like After Effects

Tags: premiere, adobe

Is there a way to receive a notification by mobile phone when an export completes in Premiere 2022, like there is now in After Effects 2022? (After Effects links to the iOS  Creative Cloud app, and sends a notification).

[image: grab]